# How to download rar file using php

Tags: php

i wrote code for downloading rar file it work's fine but

```
      $name = 'file.rar';
      $data = file_get_contents("file.rar");
      $fh = fopen("$name", 'w') or die("can't open file");
      fwrite($fh, $data);
      fclose($fh);

      header("Cache-Control: public");
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
      header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$name").";");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      readfile($name);
      exit;
```

after downloading , it shows an error unexpected end of archive while open that file,
it won't extract completely give me some suggestions thank you in advance

Comment: is the downloaded rar file in the same size?

Comment: Why are you first copying the file into memory and then write the contents over the original file instead of returning it directly? And "$name" is pointless waste, you can use $name directly.

Answer (score 1):

you can make ZIP file using following code on your web server

```
<?php
$za = new ZipArchive();

$za->open('test_with_comment.zip');
print_r($za);
var_dump($za);
$za->addFile('index.txt', 'newname.txt'); // original file , file to be added in zip

echo "numFiles: " . $za->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status: " . $za->status  . "\n";
echo "statusSys: " . $za->statusSys . "\n";
echo "filename: " . $za->filename . "\n";
echo "comment: " . $za->comment . "\n";

for ($i=0; $i<$za->numFiles;$i++) {
    echo "index: $i\n";
    print_r($za->statIndex($i));
}
echo "numFile:" . $za->numFiles . "\n";
?>
```

After that you can give link for download..

Answer (score 1):

This file.rar is generating via code?
I have tried your code without these code

```
      $data = file_get_contents("file.rar");
      $fh = fopen("$name", 'w') or die("can't open file");
      fwrite($fh, $data);
      fclose($fh);
```

Its working fine for me.