# Show a blank_page with no URL after open a link

Tags: javascript, php

I googled my question but it seems there is nothing about it on whole internet!

I have a html link that goes to a php file.That php file redirect to link for downloading a RAR file.But after download i have a page with my php file address that i dont want to be seen.i want to add another header to the php file that redirect to a blank_page that has nothing even a url.

Actually, i see many websites that using this trick,

is there any way to do that with php or js or even jquery and ... ?

> this is my php file code:
>
> ```
> header('Location: http://~~~~~~.com/xxx.RAR');
> ```

Comment: Read this question... the question shows you how to setup a script to upload files correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150836/how-to-download-rar-file-using-php

Comment: $filePath = $Down.".txt";    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$Down);

Comment: i have not any problem with download or save file.problem is after saving the file,my php file address is showed and i dont want to.i want to open up a blank page with no url after download ... .

Comment: use Curl to download the file

Comment: it wont help @jothi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple JavaScript snippet to edit the browser history + url.
The following code will set the URL to the parent domain. "Example: YourDomain.com"

```
history.replaceState( {} , '', '..' );
```

You can add this snippet to the onLoad Event of the page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body onLoad="history.replaceState( {} , '', '..' )">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @RealyNiceCode

Comment: Sure no problem, glad to be of assistance. @AidenStewart

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood it well but would that code serve?

```
$("#link").click(function() {
        location.href = 'http://~~~~~~.com/xxx.RAR';
        return false;
    });
```

This jQuery code should be on your html file and will download your file without opening a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question but
suppose this is your link in your html file using target="_blank" will open a new page
[image]

Now if you want to download a file basically you could use something like this:

```
$file = 'file/file.rar';

if (file_exists($file)) 
{
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     ob_clean();
     flush();
     readfile($file);
     exit;
}
else
{
    echo 'No installation file available for download';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the php file that redirect to the RAR file in the first place. You may modify your html link point to the RAR file directly.